# Populate new column row-by-row using values from different existing columns, using date as selection criteria

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I am using R to edit a csv of GPS points. The table looks kind of like this:

```
ID    DATE        2002.08.01    2002.08.02    2002.08.03    2002.08.04
1     8/1/2002    56            41            54            89
2     8/2/2002    65            59            69            10
3     8/2/2002    66            51            61            5
4     8/3/2002    11            21            12            32
```

Each column in the table above that has a date as the column header is  a snow depth for one specific day at that GPS point. What I want is a new column `SNOW_DEPTH`, that **only** has the snow depth for the **correct date** for that GPS point. In the example data I gave, the solution I am looking for is this:

```
ID    DATE        SNOW_DEPTH
1     8/1/2002    56
2     8/2/2002    59
3     8/2/2002    51
4     8/3/2002    12
```

Notice that the values for `SNOW_DEPTH` in the solution table are populated from snow depth values **from that row** but **the column used for population depends on the date.**

I do **not** want to list each column by name, as in my real data there are thousands of columns (all with dates as column headers). Is there a simple, **script-based R solution to my dilemma?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `tidyverse` suite of packages.  Note that I'm assuming that `DATE` is stored as a character or factor.

```
df <- read_table("ID    DATE        2002.08.01    2002.08.02    2002.08.03    2002.08.04
1     8/1/2002    56            41            54            89
2     8/2/2002    65            59            69            10
3     8/2/2002    66            51            61            5
4     8/3/2002    11            21            12            32")

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  gather(COL_DATE, SNOW_DEPTH, -ID, -DATE) %>%
  mutate( # this converts both `DATE` and `COL_DATE` to the date-time format.  If `DATE` is already in this format, skip the first conversion (you still need to convert `COL_DATE`).
    DATE = as.Date(DATE,format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
    COL_DATE = as.Date(COL_DATE, format = "%Y.%m.%d")
  ) %>%
  filter(DATE == COL_DATE) %>%
  select(-COL_DATE)
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution to my problem, and it works well on the test dataset. However, When I run it on my actual data I ge the following error: `Error in base::assign(nm, data[[nm]], envir = env_) : 
  variable names are limited to 10000 bytes` Any ideas?

Comment: do you know which command is giving you the error?  (run it in pieces, e.g. starting with `df %>% gather(COL_DATE, SNOW_DEPTH, -ID, -DATE)` to find out)

Comment: the first part: `df %>% gather(COL_DATE, SNOW_DEPTH, -ID, -DATE)`

Comment: I'm not sure where the issue is coming from.  Clearly, the two variables we are defining (`COL_DATE` and `SNOW_DEPTH`) aren't going to cause problems.  Technically, the date columns aren't technically valid column names, but we are moving them from column names to variables..  I would probably try systematically running the code on different subsets of the date columns until I figured out which one causes the problem.  At that point, if you can't figure out why the error is occurring, hopefully you have enough data to create a reproducible example so someone here can.

Comment: To avoid issues, I used `read.csv(check.names=FALSE)` instead of `read_table` or `read.table`. It works fine now.

Comment: I am getting the following error, and I am wondering if you have any ideas: `Error: Column 1 must be named`. If I set `read.csv(row.names=1)` I get an empty set of data back and it doesn't work like normal. 

When I delete the first column in Excel, it works just fine. But if I delete the first column in r `df[,1]=NULL` I get an empty set of data back as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to make a 'long' file with `ID/date/value` running down the page and then just merge this back to your initial data matching on `ID` and `date`:

```
merge(
  transform(dat[1:2], ind=format(as.Date(DATE, format="%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y.%m.%d")),
  cbind(dat["ID"], stack(dat[-(1:2)]))
)

#  ID        ind     DATE values
#1  1 2002.08.01 8/1/2002     56
#2  2 2002.08.02 8/2/2002     59
#3  3 2002.08.02 8/2/2002     51
#4  4 2002.08.03 8/3/2002     12
```

`cbind(dat["ID"], stack(dat[-(1:2)]))` gives the long file:

```
#   ID values        ind
#1   1     56 2002.08.01
#2   2     65 2002.08.01
#3   3     66 2002.08.01
# <snip>
```

And `transform(dat[1:2], ind=format(as.Date(DATE, format="%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y.%m.%d"))` gives the correctly formatted date to `merge` back on:

```
#  ID     DATE        ind
#1  1 8/1/2002 2002.08.01
#2  2 8/2/2002 2002.08.02
#3  3 8/2/2002 2002.08.02
#4  4 8/3/2002 2002.08.03
```

Where `dat` for this example was:

```
dat <- read.table(text="ID    DATE        2002.08.01    2002.08.02    2002.08.03    2002.08.04
1     8/1/2002    56            41            54            89
2     8/2/2002    65            59            69            10
3     8/2/2002    66            51            61            5
4     8/3/2002    11            21            12            32", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```